# Comparing Lists

Tags: python, list

I have 8 lists (jan, feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug) each of which contain names in list format, i.e.

```
['John Smith', 'Cat Stevens', 'Andrew Alexander', 'El Gordo Baba', 'Louis le Roy']
```

etc.

How do I compare these lists in order, and see when a name appeared (i.e. subscribed) and when a name disappeared (i.e. unsubscribed).

So, say John Smith didn't appear until February, I want to have this information. Lets say he unsubscribed in July, I want this information too (this is FAR more important than the former).

Comment: I feel like your data structure is not well suited to this. Perhaps ship these out to a database and then you can connect the name, time joined, and time left?

Comment: are there multiple subscriptions for a name? if so, which one do you want to have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = {
 'jan': ['John Smith', 'Cat Stevens', 'Andrew Alexander', 'El Gordo Baba'],
 'feb': ['Louis le Roy', 'John Smith'],
 'mar': ['Cat Stevens', 'Louis le Roy']
}

from itertools import izip

keys = 'jan feb mar'.split()
for m1,m2 in izip(keys,keys[1:]):
    a = set(data[m1])
    b = set(data[m2])
    print m1, '\n\tsubscribed:', ','.join(b-a), '\n\tquit:', ','.join(a - b )
```

result:

```
jan 
    subscribed: Louis le Roy 
    quit: Andrew Alexander,Cat Stevens,El Gordo Baba
feb 
    subscribed: Cat Stevens 
    quit: John Smith
```

Answer (score 6):

Don't use lists, use a [`set`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set) instead.

You could find who (un)subscribed between `jan` and `feb` simply using set difference:

```
subs = feb - jan
unsubs = jan - feb
```

That being said, you would be better off following Daenyth's suggestion. Put these in a database, add a `joined` and `left` date field and you'll have finer granularity than just months and you won't need to stored duplicated data.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {
 'jan': ['John Smith', 'Cat Stevens', 'Andrew Alexander', 'El Gordo Baba'],
 'feb': ['Louis le Roy', 'John Smith'],
 'mar': ['Cat Stevens', 'Louis le Roy']
}

subs = {}
unsubs = {}
for mon in data:
    for name in data[mon]:
        if name not in subs:
            subs[name] = mon
        else:
            unsubs[name] = mon
>>> subs
{'Andrew Alexander': 'jan', 'Louis le Roy': 'mar', 'John Smith': 'jan', 'El Gordo Baba': 'jan', 'Cat Stevens': 'jan'}
>>> unsubs
{'Louis le Roy': 'feb', 'John Smith': 'feb', 'Cat Stevens': 'mar'}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a starter:

```
from collections import defaultdict
dd = dict(jan=(0,jan), feb=(1, feb), ...)

appearances = defaultdict(list)

for k, (i, li) in dd.items():
   for name in li:
       appearances[name].append((i,k))

for name in appearances.keys():
    months = [ (name, i) for i, name in sorted(appearances[name]) ]
    print name, months
```

You get for each name this sorted list of pairs `(month, index)` the name appears. `index` is the index of the month. Now you can check for gaps, for a minimal index and for a maximal index.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example:

```
jan,feb,mar,apr,may,jun,jul,aug = [1],[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4],[3,4],[4],[]
months = [set(m) for m in [jan,feb,mar,apr,may,jun,jul,aug]]
changes = [(list(b-a), list(a-b)) for a, b in zip(months, months[1:])]

>>> changes
[([2], []), ([3], []), ([4], []), ([], [1]), ([], [2]), ([], [3]), ([], [4])]
```

Each element in `changes` is a transition from one month to the next, where the first item in the tuple is a list of all that were added, and the second item in the tuple is a list of all that left.